# Fix inability of a ComboBox to bind an observalbe collection

Tags: .net, wpf, binding, combobox

I have a ComboBox withing a GridView column:

```
...
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True" ColumnHeaderToolTip="Info test">
               <GridViewColumn Header="Number" Width="120">
                  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=extensions}" Width="105" IsEditable="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" BorderThickness="0">
                           <ComboBox.Resources>
                              <sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">15</sys:Double>
                           </ComboBox.Resources>
                        </ComboBox>
                     </DataTemplate>
                  </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
...
```

In the code behind, "extensions" is an `ObserverableCollection<string>` that is 100% getting initialized and populated (this is in the class constructor):

```
public partial class MyForm : Window
{
   ...
   public ObservableCollection<string> extensions;
   ...

   public MyForm()
   {
      ...
      Initialize();
   }

   private Initialize()
   {
       extensions = new ObservableCollection<string>();
       extensions.Add("x100");
       extensions.Add("x101");
   }
}
```

But when the application runs while the comboboxes appear, the binding never happens.  What additional step(s) are required for this to be complete/correct?

Comment: Is your extensions is a public property?

Comment: @MiklósBalogh Yeah.  I declare it as public.  I'll update my post to clarify this.  Thank.s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First do not use public field, use properties instead. As far as I know public fields doesn't work with binding.

```
public ObservableCollection<string> extensions {get; private set;}
```

Second, probably the datacontext of the combobox is not set to the MyForm instance.
Try this

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=extensions, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type MyForm}}}" ... >
```

Comment: If I add in the additional code I get an error "Type MyForm was not found."

Comment: probably there are prefix what your IDE generated to reach that class

Comment: I've not done too much WPF, so may I ask what kind of prefix(es) I might be looking for?

Comment: please post the remaining part of your xaml, especially the header

Comment: Hey, got it, thanks.  By the way my project was set up I just need to do `Ancestor=Window` for the relative source.  Now I'm getting the expected behavior.